# How to set properties for super script in xsl

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

This is my code:

```
<fo:block>
<fo:inline text-decoration="underline" font-weight="bold">29<fo:inline vertical-align="super" font-size="5pt">th</fo:inline>St,</fo:inline>.
</fo:block>
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

but I need it to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align="super"` is a convenience feature, but you can instead use either a length or a percentage as the value of `vertical-align` to get the effect that you want.  By the look of your sample, you might even want to try `vertical-align="middle"`.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#vertical-align, but since, in XSL-FO, `vertical-align` is a shorthand for multiple properties, also see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#baseline-shift.